# Hadoop HDFS Deployment

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to understand the relationship between HDFS and the [various other constituents](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.2/bk_getting-started-guide/content/ch_hdp1_getting_started_chp3.html) of a typical Hadoop cluster. Is HDFS only supposed to be running on `NameNodes` and `DataNodes`, or is it running on every single node type (`MasterNode`, `SlaveNodes`, `ZooKeeperNode`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the read/write process in Hadoop-The definitve Guide book. No all data is stored on every node. There are few concepts to frequently monitor the process and interact accordingly. Please revisit your theoretical concepts. Happy learning

Comment: Sorry @Ramzy but the SO community frowns upon answers that just mention links to the documentation, let alone commercial (non-free) documentation like a book, let alone no links at all. ;-) I assume by "*All data is stored on every node*", you mean that each node must be running HDFS (or a compatible OS), **yes**?

Comment: In reality each node is a machine, and they participate in the entire Hadoop work flow. Data moves around, infact code moves around here in Hadoop and the machines share the responsibility. Regarding book, sorry no idea about what you were mentioning. The question you asked, is at high level, and answer can be found in that book in a specific chapter. Happy Learning

Comment: Thanks again @Ramzy, I'll happily give you the green check if you can **please** just confirm what I am asking here: that all nodes must in fact run HDFS. **Yes?!?** Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, atleast for the task which the node is supposed to perform. As I mentioned, each node performs a task like name node, data node etc. When you treat a node a name node, it has specific requirements different than other like a region server node.